# How to force git to update single file

Tags: git

I have a file which should be updated on github.
Although when i try to update this file with command

```
$ git commit -m 'update' package.json
```

I recieve nothing to commit, working three clean.

Can i force git to update this file any way?

Comment: This seems like a basic git question. You should read more about commiting and staging in general. There are many resources, like [this one](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2): Chapter 2 is all for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git add package.json; git commit -m 'update'
```

Comment: i tried it.
When i added it it wosn't throwing error. And on git commit -m 'update' it throwed same error. Nothing to commit

Comment: @Vlad Are there any changes to commit yet? Have you tried `git push` to see an effect on Github?

Comment: there are have to be changes because this file was updated previously. And now other git members have problem because of un updated package.json. But i cannot understan why git doesnt want to update this file

Comment: What happen when you type `git status`? Is `package.json` file there?

Comment: when i type 'git status'  it says: Your branch is up to date, nothing to commit.
But what i noticed that page which i was working on didn't appear on server.
It seems  that git didn't load all files to github. And now says there are nothing to commit